# Undoubtedly wrong answer

Tags: discussion

This answer to [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/why-do-turbine-engines-take-so-long-to-spool-up/) is incorrect on several levels.

1. The question was about turbine engines, the answer was about jet engines.
2. The answer is about starting the engine, but the question does not mention that.
3. The answer is incorrect about the reason turbine engines take so long to spool up. A turbine engine with the same rotational inertia as a piston engine will definitely start slower. The answer is not consistent with that fact.
4. If the question is, in fact, about starting, a turbine engine has to spin much faster than a piston engine in order to start. After ignition (at the higher speed), a turbine engine cannot accelerate to idle (an even higher speed) too fast or it overheats.
5. An upvoted comment compares the starting speed of an A320 engine to a piston engine?
6. The battery is not normally the limiting factor for a turbine engine start. The starter motor is turned off well before a turbine engine reaches idle speed.

I don't know what, if anything, should be done about it, but I do know that this kind of thing does not make the site look good.

Comment: which answer? you can point at it directly using the 'share' link below each item.

Comment: The accepted answer.

Comment: Umm, a jet engine ***is*** a turbine engine....

Comment: But a turbine engine doesn't have to be a jet. It can be a turboprop.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure that the distinction between the two is really an issue here.  :)

Answer (score 7):

About the only reasonable thing to do is to provide a better answer and down-vote the accepted answer if you feel that it is warranted.

Hopefully the asker will then accept the better one, but even if not then, over time hopefully people reading the answers will upvote the better answer *and* down vote the accepted one.

These things work themselves out over time.

Comment: And a specific note: a "very low quality" flag is not suitable for a wrong answer.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Agreed!  There aren't any flags that are suitable for an answer that actually attempts to answer the question, even if it is incorrect.

Comment: I understand -- I didn't flag it. I deleted my answer so this wouldn't be a "mine is better" argument.

Comment: @xpda Yeah, I think that Qantas was just pointing that out for the benefit of future visitors that don't know...

Comment: @xpda Unfortunately, your answer **was** better so you shouldn't have deleted it, lol.

Comment: Related: [What should we do in the event that an answer is absolutely incorrect?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186609/195862)