# Why is this clearly wrong answer "Looks OK"?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-answer, low-quality

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/57671

It is clearly wrong as pointed out in a comment, which makes it beyond saving, and the single Looks OK closed the review.

Deleting low-quality beyond-saving regardless of an attempt at an answer, is a legit reason for deletion [per the help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user). Otherwise the noise-level will increase.

> #### When should I vote to delete an answer?
>
> You may vote to delete answers in the following cases:
>
> - The answer is extremely low quality: There is little to no scope for improvement
> - ...

I can understand not deleting so-so answers, especially on programming sites (to have a visible record of what not to do), but not this.

Comment: relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/376358

Answer (score 8):

It is my understanding that flags should not be used to mark answers that are factually wrong. We delete answers if they are spam or if they do not actually attempt to answer the question. The answer you are talking about is clearly wrong, but it *does* attempt to answer the question. It should be downvoted (as it has been), but not deleted, since there is nothing technically wrong with the answer itself (just something wrong with the content of the answer).

See

[Undoubtedly wrong answer](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198/undoubtedly-wrong-answer)

[What should we do in the event that an answer is absolutely incorrect?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186608/what-should-we-do-in-the-event-that-an-answer-is-absolutely-incorrect/)

[What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing/180029#180029)

etc.

"declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer" is the reply when you flag a wrong answer as "not an answer"

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with this logic, but it's how I've learned to handle it after having several of my own flags rejected after flagging answers that are obviously wrong

Answer (score 3):

I would have voted to delete as low quality, however I know some folks will not vote to delete if a post still looks like an attempt to answer. In those instances, I hope they still downvote, and eventually the post will vanish as it collects a lot of downvotes.

I wouldn't necessarily worry about it though - I added my downvote. Others will do the same. It won't last long.

Comment: Coming from your experience I'm glad to know my viewpoint isn't wrong. Hopefully this post gets that attention, as the Looks OK closed the review. The downvoters deserve their -1 back :-)

Comment: Oh, I've now flagged as not an answer - so it may come into the review queue again :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop no, it won't https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3958/1467

Comment: @Federico - Thanks for the confirmation. I wasn't sure.

Comment: I flagged it as ",not an answer" but after a closer look at the flag description changed to "low quality"

Comment: Re -- "Eventually the post will vanish as it collects a lot of downvotes." -- how many downvotes does it take for a post to vanish?  *And who can still see it at that point?*  Author of post?  People with a certain number of rep points?  Just curious.  My impression from here https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers is that a question with a -1 score is eligible to be *voted* for deletion, but that's not the same as "disappearing".  Would love to understand better.

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing questions with answers? _Questions_ with negative score and no positive-score answers will be deleted eventually by the roomba script, but I don't think that's true of answers. AFAIK, those need delete votes to get rid of them.