# Do we still delete "demonstrably wrong" answers?

Tags: support, review

I recently asked an answer-specific question, [Why is this clearly wrong answer "Looks OK"?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4206/14897), followed by a post on the main meta, [Can we have more options for low-quality reviews?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364255/392799), an answer to which led me to check if we have a site consensus, which it turns out we do(!):

> Answers should be
>
> - **Removed** if they are clearly, demonstrably wrong
> - ...
>
> — The answer to [Is scientific rigour required in our answers?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/392/14897) (Jan 2015)

I remember reading that phrase elsewhere on the site, perhaps a Help Center page.

**Q:** is that consensus still valid?

I'm not asking to revisit it, I'm just checking it wasn't superseded by something else—the linked post does not contain the keywords *reference* and *citation,* so it was **not** easy to find.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that counts as consensus. The answer you quote has been up-voted three times, but a comment below opposing the "delete when wrong" doctrine has been up-voted twice.

I've never been in favour of deleting demonstrably wrong answers just because they are wrong. That is what the down-voting function is for.

If people want to argue, [for example](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/86939/19), that lift is defined along the vertical instead of perpendicular to the relative airflow (which is the generally accepted definition), then by all means let them argue that.

If people want to go to great lengths to demonstrate their lack of basic understanding of physics, then by all means let them demonstrate that.

If people want to argue that emergency beacons have a [very short range](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/2451/19), up to the point that they are useless, then please let them argue that.

If you disagree with them, just down vote and leave a (nice!) explanatory comment.

Let's reserve the delete function for abusive posts, spam, very low quality answer and posts that should be converted to comments.